# How can I add multiple project dependencies to a configuration in one instruction in gradle

Tags: dependencies, gradle, dependency-management

I am trying to add multiple project in one instruction dependencies (to use only one configuration closure) with gradle but I don't know  how to do it.

If try to do

```
configurationName (
    project('subProject1') ,
    project('subProject2'),
) {
    transitive = false
}
```

I got an error at the configuration step, but

```
configurationName (
    project('subProject1') ,
) {
    transitive = false
}

configurationName (
    project('subProject2') ,
) {
    transitive = false
}
```

I don't know why, when

```
configurationName(
    [group: 'commons-dbutils', name: 'commons-dbutils', version: '1.5'],
    [group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-tx', version: springVersion],
    'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'
)
```

works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to repeat `{ transitive = false }` for each project dependency. Alternatively, you can make the whole configuration non-transitive (`configurations.configurationName { transitive = false }`).